# Automatic database manipulation in laravel every month

Tags: php, laravel, logic

I am searching all over since two days but can't find a proper way to do what I want! I have a database table that I want to update every month. So, I am designing an API with Laravel, and I would like to execute a block of SQL statement ONLY ONCE IN THE MONTH when a specific function is called.
For Instance inside my index function that retrieve all the row of a table, I want to check if the current date is above a date in the column if it is executed code inside the INDEX function ONLY ONCE then when the function is called again within that same month do not execute at all. I have written the logic for database manipulation, but can't run the code only once when the INDEX function is executed. It keeps executing the BLOCK OF CODE WITHIN. So I am wondering how to do such TASK. I have seen about CRON Job but, it is not what I want. I want the task to be done without executing any command. Below is the code

```
public function getAllOrder(){  
  //here executed will be a boolean to record if the function is executed or not. 
  if(!$executed && $todayDate < "SOMEDATTE"){
    //run function under only once//
    function createOrder(){
    
    }
  }
  else{
    //no order to be created
  }
}
```

The Above code is just to show what i want.

Comment: If you only want to run something once a month, then what is the reason for not wanting to use a cronjob, which would be the ideal solution? If you want to call it from index, you will need to keep the state of it's execution somewhere (like in a database) and check that on every request, which just seems like unnecessary complexity.

Comment: @Magnus Presumably because he only wants it to run once a month *when something else happens*?

Comment: You must setup you Laravel cron properly and schedule a job. That's the way. Without cron you will need to put a code that run in every request (or on some requests) that check's if today is the day to run the job and check somewhere if the job was already done. But that's reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @GilesBennett - Maybe, but I tend to avoid making assumptions since many questions here turns out to be XY problems.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I don't think it's really an assumption given that the OP says "I would like to execute a block of SQL statement ONLY ONCE IN THE MONTH when a specific function is called" (emphasis theirs).

Comment: @GilesBennett - Maybe we should let the OP answer my question instead? Very often when people ask questions like this, it often turns out that they don't really need what they believe they need, or that there are even more restrictions/specifications that will affect what suggestions actually fit their needs. Asking the OP to explain why is often a good way to weed out the _real_ question, which can save both us and the OP time.

Comment: May be I am mis-understanding cron job. I 've seen that before your cron job will run, you need to run a command first. the command you've created. And this is not what i want. I tested my logic in the index function but, the issue is that it runs my code again. but want it to run only once even if i run the index many times within that same month

Comment: @EliasSoares read above answer

Comment: If all you want to do is to make sure that you only run some specific code once a month, then the best solution would be to create a command in Laravel that does what you want to do and then set up a cron job to execute that command once a month. A cron job is just a scheduled execution of a command. That command can be anything, really.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson according to my previous answer, am i misunderstanding cron job?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by _"before your cron job will run, you need to run a command first. the command you've created"_. As I said, a cron job is just a scheduled execution of a command, so no, you don't need to do anything _before_ your cron job. And if you have the code you want to run in your index file, just move it to a Laravel CLI command and execute that using cron instead.

Comment: let assumes this schedule: 
$schedule->call(function () {
            DB::table('recent_users')->delete();
        })->daily();
before that code will run am I not going to run php artisan schedule:run ????? 
and me i don't want to do such operation. i want my task be done only when i run the INDEX function.

Comment: This whole discussion could have been avoided if you just answered _why_ you don't want to execute a command over adding a bunch of complex logic to your index file (that will be execute _on every request_) that most likely will be open for race conditions. That first comment also mentioned the flow you need to implement. What have you actually tried? The posted code just looks like some vague pseudo code and not a real attempt.

Comment: I am designing an API, and the task I want to perform have to be done without anyone need to execute a command. For instance, you are designing a website where you need to list all data in the table ORDER. Now before the data in that table will be retrieved, check the table and if in the table the column name date is greater than your current date then insert a new row in that table. You get me now???

Comment: "_am I not going to run php artisan schedule:run ?????_" No, you don't. That's the command you set up as your cron job. That command runs every minute and checks on its own if it needs to run any other task at the time it has been called. [Running The Scheduler](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling#running-the-scheduler)

Comment: @brombeer really??? can you just give me an example? and how will i know that it is really running. Do it with the simplest code below: 
$schedule->call(function () {
            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'Email has been sent.'
            ], Response::HTTP_OK);
        })->everyMinute();

Comment: I linked the Laravel documentation for Scheduling tasks, this explains everything in detail. "_how will i know that it is really running_" Implement a mechanism that notifies you. How will you know that your "index" method is called? If no one visits your site, your "index" method will _never_ be called

Comment: @brombeer I've seen it! Thanks, now I need to learn about adding cron entries on a server

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the solution:** 
Get the date from your database table

```
$table=Table::find($id);
```

Get only month

```
$tableMonth = $table->date->format('m');
```

Get current month

```
$currentMonth = Carbon::now()->format('m');
```

Check if table month is equal with the current month

```
 if($tableMonth == $currentMonth){
      //run function under only once
 }else{
      //no order to be created
 }
```

**If you need to get all data from your table you should do that:**

```
 $tables=Table::all();
 $currentMonth = Carbon::now()->format('m');
 foreach($tables as $table){
    if($table->date->format('m') == $currentMonth){
         //run function under only once
    }else{
         //no order to be created
    }
 }
```